# how to commit a update via gitlab api?

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-api, python-gitlab

I wanna do some gitlab operation via python and gitlab-api.
there is only one file called `pg.py` in my repository.

```
url = 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/v3/projects/4/repository/commits'
data = {"id":4, "branch_name":"master","commit_message":"commit via api","actions":[{"action":"update","file_path":"pg.py"}]}
files = {'file':('pg.py',open('/opt/commitapp/pg.py','rb'),'text/x-python',{'Expires':'0'})}
headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN":"xxxx"}

r = requests.post(url=url,data=data,files=files,headers=headers)
```

but I got the reply:

```
r.text
u'{"error":"actions is invalid"}'
```

besides, it this the right way to upload files?

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html, it seems that `actions` need to contain `content` if  `action` is `update`

> content - File content, required for all except delete. Optional for move

Comment: I check the document again,content - File content. so I type `with open('.../pg.py') as fp: fcontent=fp.read()` and then I update the action dict,but it still return code 400 with _actions is invalid_.

Comment: `base64 -w0 "./pg.py"`